# Атрибут которого равен

Tags: jquery

Запилил слайдер! Мне нужно в активный слад вставить блок и нужно сделать это по атрибуту index. Вот что я написал:

```
$('.vidy .vidy__slide-content').attr('index', i).append(last);
```

Ну прикол что index присвоится  значение `i`, а мне нужно что бы он вставил в блок с index `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать .eq();

```
$('.vidy .vidy__slide-content').eq(i).append(last);
```